# ValueError Iterating List of Tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, tuples

I have a list containing tuples, and I want to replace the `None` objects in one of the tuples with `'None'` strings.

Here is my code:

```
x = [('hello','there'),(None,'world',None)]
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        if j is None:
            n = x.index(i)
            l = list(x[n])
            m = x[n].index(j)
            l[m] = 'None'
            x[n] = tuple(l)
```

However, it throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ValueError: (None, 'world', None) is not in list
```

How can I iterate over the tuple properly to replace both `None` objects with `'None'` strings?

Comment: Tuples are immutable - I would suggest using a different data structure if you need it to be dynamic.

Comment: It's because you have two None's and once you encounter the first None you change the value of that i, yet you still hold that old value in memory. For instance it starts out as `(None, 'world', None)` yet when you change it once it becomes `('None', 'world', None)` but your i still holds the original value in memory and when you search for that with `.index` it isn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `None` value is changed to `'None'`, `j` is still `(None, 'world', None)`.  You're updating `x[n]`, but not `j`.  Your code works if you iterate through `x` directly.

```
x = [('hello','there'),(None,'world',None)]
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in x[i]:
        if j is None:
            n = i
            l = list(x[n])
            m = x[n].index(j)
            l[m] = 'None'
            x[n] = tuple(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> x = [('hello', 'there'),(None, 'world', None)]
>>> [tuple('None' if item is None else item for item in tup) for tup in x]
[('hello', 'there'), ('None', 'world', 'None')]
```

Answer (score 2):

The first time you find `None` you run

```
x[n] = tuple(l)
```

changing `(None,'world',None)` to `('None','world',None)`. The second time you find `None` you run

```
x.index((None,'world',None))
```

but now x is

```
x = [('hello','there'),('None','world',None)]
```

so it doesn't contain the `(None,'world',None)`, yielding you a value error